# Creating a 'line connected' recyclerview with cardviews

Tags: android, android-layout, listview, android-recyclerview

how can I create the below layout where each record is a recyclerview record..I already have a recyclerview but how can i set the left icons to be connected by a line as shown below and what of the data on the right, is that a cardview?

[image]

Thanks...Any help would be appreciated. My left icons are all going to be the same so i can do it in xml..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need at least two types of view.

One is this header with icon and day of week, and the second one is this line with card view and bottom margines. If you position this icon and this line properly it will looks like it is connected.

[image: header layout]

[image: content layout]